# contact form not sending senders email

Tags: php, email, contact-form

i don't know if this is a common problem but i can't seem to understand why it is happening. 
I am trying to process a form and have it send the details to an email. Simple enough.
Here is the PHP code for it. When someone fills the form up it shows everything except the senders email. It comes out as unknown sender. Does anyone know how i can fix it?
Thanks a lot to anyone who takes time out to look at this.

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
$recipient="emailx@gmail.com";
$subject="Form to email message";
$Name=$_POST["Name"];
$Phone=$_POST["Phone"]; 
$senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
$comments=$_POST["comments"];

$mailBody="Name: $Name\nPhone: $Phone\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$comments";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $Name <$comments>");

$thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: If `$senderEmail` or `$Name` or any of these values contains the string "unknown sender" then clearly that's the value being posted to the form.  In that case this code is doing exactly what it's intended to do.

Comment: The `From` is `$comments` shouldn't it be `$senderEmail`?

Comment: @chris85 - from what it looks like, that is definitely the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[chris85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85) answered the question in the comments:

> The `From` is `$comments` shouldn't it be `$senderEmail`?

However, it's not quite that simple. You can't just pick any `from` email address and expect it to work. The email client will most likely spam your emails if you try to spoof the from address.

Whenever you change the `From` header you also need to change the `reply-to` header, in your case, You should probably put the `From` header as one of the email addresses on your server and only change the `reply-to` header to whatever the user in-putted. That way your messages are more likely to not be spammed because it doesn't look like you're trying to be sneaky.

Another option is to use a simple library to take care of all this for you.

Here's a real simple one I wrote: http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2014/08/wrapper-for-phps-mail-function.html

Comment: I understand what you said. I also found out why it was giving me an empty email address for that field since  $Name <$comments>"); was wrong.                                                                                                                      I fixed that and it sends the full information asked in the form. Just the sender address is unkown but i can fix that in due time. Another question i have is when i try using the form in my server (free hosting) it is fine. When i try to use it on another server ( runs through cloudflare ) it gives me 504 gateway error. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the header is not set correctly.
Try something like this:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
  $recipient="emailx@gmail.com";
  $subject="Form to email message";
  $Name=$_POST["Name"];
  $Phone=$_POST["Phone"]; 
  $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
  $comments=$_POST["comments"];
  $header = "From: $senderEmail" . "\r\n" .
     "Reply-To: $senderEmail" . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  $mailBody="Name: $Name\nPhone: $Phone\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$comments";

  mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, $header);

  $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

The function reference for the php `mail` function can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).